# Proper async await syntax for fetching data using useEffect hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I have used **async** for anonymous function inside useEffect hook. I have done this so that I can **await** for the response that I am fetching. Although this is working fine, I've read somewhere on the web that it is a bad practice to write async await inside useEffect hook like this without any proper explaination for it. So just wanted to ask you guys if this is a good practice or bad practice. If it is a bad practice, then what is the disadvantage of writing async await like this in useEffect, and also wanted to know an alternative for this. **Big THANKS for your time and help.**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function FetchPractice() {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    const data = await response.json();
    setApiData(data);
  });

  return (
    <>
      {apiData.map((post) => (
        <div
          key={post.id}
          style={{
            border: "1px solid black",
            margin: "16px",
            padding: "16px",
            backgroundColor: "#2d2d2d",
            color: "white",
            fontWeight: "bold",
          }}
        >
          {JSON.stringify(post)}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: In this way, your API response data is only available to this component only. To avoid that you can use Redux to make it globally accessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not make your `useEffect` function `async`, but you can create an `async` function inside `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const getDatas = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        const data = await response.json();
        setApiData(data);
    }
    getDatas()
});
```

or even

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        const data = await response.json();
        setApiData(data);
    )()
});
```

Comment: Thanks !! I get your point but my code is also working fine, then what is the issue with that, I want to know the problem associated with it.

Comment: A moderator has added the link to the "why" :)

Comment: What's the advantage of this over having the async function outside of useEffect with useCallback?